# PRIMARY KEY must be unique

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to write some data to a table in a database which I am creating.
However, I am facing with an integrity error like:

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) PRIMARY KEY must be unique

My question is how to avoid these errors as I will run a couple of times the script

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are creating an object with an already existing primary key, and it's not accepted by SQLite. Verify it by querying the db with something like

```
select * from airport where id = 6256
```

If the query returns a result, you need to change the id of the airport you are saving. Since you use the autoincrement, you **don't need** to specify an id and the DBMS will assign the next free id in that table.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes for sure this value is inserted in the table. But my question is how to avoid these errors as I will run a couple of times the script

Comment: You can simply not write an id to assign, the dbms will assign that automatically